# Use of Case function within Order By clause of ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql, sql-server

`dAdmit` and `dDischarge` are dates. So, this code is ordering by 2 dates. But the `Case` statement returns either a 1 or 0, dependent on whether `dDischarge` is null or not.

I'm confused by the use of the `CASE` statement. How can a 1 or 0 be used in the ordering of dates?

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
  PARTITION BY pHSSid
  ORDER BY
    dAdmit
    , CASE WHEN dDischarge IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    , dDischarge
) AS wSSeq
```

Using SQL Server.

I've searched for examples of `CASE` statements within `ORDER BY` clauses but haven't found any that include dates and the 0/1 option.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: Its not ordering by 2 days, its ordering by date, bit, date.

Comment: FWIW, I'd remove the CASE expression by using `ORDER BY dAdmit, coalesce(dDischarge, '29991231')`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - converting my comment to an answer.

The `CASE` expression in the `ORDER BY` clause is a very useful method of classifying the data into groups.

I'll assume, for ease of demonstration, that these are patients (given that you have date admitted and discharged).

The person who wrote this was probably given the task 'Please provide a list of all patients with their admission and discharge dates. I want them grouped/order by their admission date, and then for each of those dates, I want them ordered by their discharge date - with those who haven't yet been discharged at the bottom.'

If you just did an `ORDER BY dAdmit, dDischarge` it's not clear where those who haven't been discharged will go. Will those who haven't been discharged (dDischarge = NULL) be put at the top of each day's list? Or at the bottom?

The method with the CASE statement allows you to force that the dDischarge = NULL rows go at the bottom of each day. Anyone with *any* discharge date will get 0, and therefore be sorted before those without discharge dates.

The net effect will be sorting by dAdmit, then dDischarge (and those with NULL dDischarge dates will be at the bottom because they get a '1' in the second check, compared to those who do have a date, who get a 0 for that check).

Here is an example of data sorted with the above, showing the results of the CASE in the middle column. You can see it sorts by column 1, then 2, then 3.

```
dAdmit          CASE        dDischarge
2023-01-01      0           2023-01-01
2023-01-01      0           2023-01-02
2023-01-01      0           2023-01-02
2023-01-01      1           NULL
2023-01-02      0           2023-01-02
2023-01-02      0           2023-01-02
2023-01-02      0           2023-01-03
2023-01-02      1           NULL
2023-01-02      1           NULL
2023-01-02      1           NULL
2023-01-03      1           NULL
```

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: @seanb Thanks.  That answer was very clear. The results table you provided was valuable.  I didn't realize that the CASE expression was creating a 'virtual column' as part of the sorting process.